# t-SNE map into 2D or 3D plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot

```
features =  ["Ask1", "Bid1", "smooth_midprice", "BidSize1", "AskSize1"]

client = InfluxDBClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=8086, database='data',
                        username=username, password=password)

series = "DCIX_2016_11_15"

sql = "SELECT * FROM {} where time  >= '{}' AND time <= '{}' ".format(series,FROMT,TOT)

df = pd.DataFrame(client.query(sql).get_points())

#Separating out the features
X = df.loc[:, features].values

# Standardizing the features
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=3, n_jobs=5).fit_transform(X)
```

I would like map my 5 features into a 2D or 3D plot. I am a bit confused how to do that. How can I build a plot from that information?

Comment: You don't mention what package you are using, but I assume scikit-learn. Their documentation is pretty thorough: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html. What problem are you running into exactly? Seems you are doing what you need to be doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already have most of the work done. t-SNE is a common visualization for understanding high-dimensional data, and right now the variable `tsne` is an array where each row represents a set of (x, y, z) coordinates from the obtained embedding. You could use other visualizations if you would like, but t-SNE is probably a good starting place.

As far as actually seeing the results, even though you have the coordinates available you still need to plot them somehow. The `matplotlib` library is a good option, and that's what we'll use here.

**To plot in 2D** you have a couple of options. You can either keep most of your code the same and simply perform a 2D t-SNE with

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, n_jobs=5).fit_transform(X)
```

Or you can just use the components you have and only look at two of them at a time. The following snippet should handle either case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(*zip(*tsne[:,:2]))
plt.show()
```

The `zip(*...)` transposes your data so that you can pass the x coordinates and the y coordinates individually to `scatter()`, and the `[:,:2]` piece selects two coordinates to view. You could ignore it if your data is already 2D, or you could replace it with something like `[:,[0,2]]` to view, for example, the 0th and 2nd features in higher-dimensional data rather than just the first 2.

**To plot in 3D** the code looks much the same, at least for a minimal version.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(*zip(*tsne))
plt.show()
```

The main differences are a use of 3D plotting libraries and making a 3D subplot.

**Adding color:** t-SNE visualizations are typically more helpful if they're color-coded somehow. One example might be the smooth midprice you currently have stored in `X[:,2]`. For exploratory visualizations, I find 2D plots more helpful, so I'll use that as the example:

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*tsne[:,:2]), c=X[:,2])
```

You still need the imports and whatnot, but by passing the keyword argument `c` you can color code the scatter plot. To adjust how that numeric data is displayed, you could use a different color map like so:

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*tsne[:,:2]), c=X[:,2], cmap='RdBu')
```

As the name might suggest, this colormap consists of a gradient between red and blue, and the lower values of `X[:,2]` will correspond to red.

Comment: Can you tell how to fix the colours I want? I have five features, so the colours could be `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange']`.

Comment: As best as I can tell, that doesn't really apply to this problem. Each **point** you are graphing has 3 features, and those 3 features are a complex combination of the original 5 features. There is no way to look at a point and say it is an "Ask1" point, so there wouldn't really be a reason to color it red based on that feature. The t-SNE embedding attempts to arrange your data so that similar things are next to eachother, and the color exists to reveal other properties in that embedding.

Comment: You showed me the example for 2D representation, but what about the 3D representation?

Comment: That was the second example with `projection='3d'` and whatnot.

Comment: Yes, but this is not fine, i.e. `ax.scatter(*zip(*tsne), c=X[:,2], cmap='RdBu')`. How can I fix that for the 3D part?

Comment: What's it not doing that it should be? When combined with the imports and other supporting code, it gives a scatter plot where each point in the plot corresponds to one point from the t-SNE output, it colors them according to `smooth_midprice`, and it uses a red->blue colormap to do so. Coloring a t-SNE plot based on the five features is not possible. What would you like this code to do exactly?

Comment: I want to take many features (ie. ML featuring purposes) and having a clear 2D or 3D representation of the feature inputs.

Comment: But what kind of 2D or 3D representation? The code provided does that (unless it crashes on your machine or something?). What properties does it lack that you want satisfied? I really do want to help, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am wrong the way I use it. I would like now to have a clear representation on the labels (i.e machine learning purposes). How can I use t-SNE for having a representation of the labels (i.e. clouds representation)?